# Concept of heat of reaction in a isolated system

Tags: thermodynamics

One description of the concept is that heat of reaction (exothermic) is the quantity of heat that would given off to the surrounding by the product of a reaction if we allow the product to cool down.

If this description is valid for all exothermic reaction in a isolated system, would it also be valid for all endothermic reactions??

Answer (score 1):

When chemical bonds are broken potential energy increases.  When they are made potential energy decreases. A loss in PE raises kinetic energy and a gain in PE lowers KE.  Since all reactions involve bond breaking and bond making the reaction will involve an increase or decrease in PE and a decrease or increase in KE.  When KE of the system increases, a system in contact with the surroundings will lose energy as heat (exothermic).  When KE of the system decreases a system in contact with the surroundings will gain energy as heat (endothermic).  In an isolated system "exothermic" reactions just raise temperature and "endothermic" reactions just lower temperature.

Comment: Wrong, potential energy would increase when bonds are formed. More heat capacity

Comment: Actually I kinda get it: if the reaction is endothermic, you can't really cool it off because the energy is used for bond forming, right?

Comment: No.  Bond formation is spontaneous compared to separate atoms.  Think of the reaction as the breaking of all the bonds in the reactants that aren't in the products.  The fragments then form the bonds that are in the products but not in the reactants.  It does NOT take energy to make a bond any more than it takes energy for an object to fall from a height to the earth.